# How do you implement the factorial function in C++ with proper error handling?

Tags: c++

I asked this before but it was closed by people who didn't understand the question. I'm not looking for just a loop, I am looking for how you would do it for production code with stuff like error handling for arguments and overflows.

And please don't just say "use library X" unless you can link to the code for said library and it actually addresses these concerns.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with factorial, and is about "programming properly"?

Comment: Pretty much yea. I wouldn't say it doesn't entirely have nothing to do with factorial because I suppose you wouldn't want heavy-weight error handling for such as simple problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be something as simple as:

```
unsigned factorial(unsigned n)
{
   if (n > theUpperThreshold)
      throw ExceptionFormYourMathLibrary("Explain that n! can't be represented by unsigned");

   return lookupTable[n];      
}
```

Unless your math library provides some big integer class as well.

Answer (score 9):

Use table lookup. You won't need big table, since factorial will overflow 64 bit double precision variable range very quickly. You only need to store function values for argument values from 0 to 170. Anything outside that range should generate an error.

Comment: To add to this, you could also use templates to generate the list.

Comment: And how do you generator that error? Exceptions? Returning a -1? An assertion? Should I use out-parameters and return a 0 for success? There are a lot of options here.

Comment: Don't use out-parameters for such a simple function. Either return -1 or throw an exception.

Comment: Well which one is the proper way to do it in C++ and which will annoy those who are using my function?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the domain of the input.

If you are using a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, you shouldn't use a loop at all:  just use a lookup table.  There are not very many `n` for which `n!` is representable by a 64-bit integer.  With a lookup table, checking for overflow is easy:  if there isn't an entry for `n` in the lookup table, it's obviously out of range.

If the input is larger than that then presumably you will be using some sort of "big integer" class and overflow is unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: Did you mean to say "if your **output** is a 32-bit or 64-bit integer?"

Comment: @Ken:  Yes, in fact that is what I meant.  Thank you.

Comment: @Howard:  I knew it was something small; after 6! my brain threw an overflow exception so I stopped there.

Comment: <chuckle> I deleted my comment after only 5 seconds.  You found it anyway!  Yeah, 0-20 for unsigned 64 bit.  As pic11 says, 0-170 for 64 bit double precision.  0-12 for unsigned 32 bit.  The table solution sounds good to me, unless you want to handle BigInt.  And in that case the design probably depends on BigInt details.